# If I'd implement static Inheritance how would it fare "dynamically" against creating instances and calling a virtual Method?

Tags: c#, inheritance, static, virtual

Alright so I created a StaticInheritance Analyzer in Roslyn and everything kinda works alright. But I had to figure that I couldn't use those static methods dynamically from a base class like regular virtual and abstract methods(which wouldn't baffle anyone but me). So I thought creating a small API that caches all subclasses at startup and then fires up the Inheritance Tree when let's say calling `StaticInheritance.Invoke<TKnownBaseClass>(Type subclass, string staticInheritanceMethod)`.

My Question is now: how would it fare against instantiating an object using Activator, casting it to TKnownBaseClass and calling its virtual method?

Comment: Only you know how you're implementing this, so only you can measure the different approaches. Why do you want to do this? Attempting to redefine the constraints of a programming language seems foolhardy. There are enough holes in the concept of static inheritance that it doesn't feature in the language. I'd be interested to know what your use-case is for this.

Comment: Well I stumbled upon some use cases where i thought it would make more sense to have iherited statics. And at one point i just said. Fuck it let's do it. Right now I figure I Could've just created a little helper method that does what i described for the instance method. But now i'm here and already made the Analyzer, so i fugred the last steps wouldnt hurt that much. If it was performant enough